# datepicker, using parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a day input, a month input and a year input, and a datepicker which is shown. When clicking an image, I put the day, month and year in each input.

Now my problem is the day, month and year inputs' ids will change dynamically and I would like to specifiy them as parameters:

```
        <input name="dayXX" id="dayXX"> 
        <input name="monthXX" id="monthXX"> 
        <input name="yearXX" id="yearXX">  
        <input name="calendario" id="calendario" onclick="$(this).openDatepicker();">
        <input type="hidden" id="datepicker">

       $(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            firstDay: 0,
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March',
            'April', 'May', 'June',
            'July', 'August', 'September',
            'October', 'November', 'December'],
            dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
            dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

       });
     });



   jQuery(function($) {

      $.fn.openDatepicker = function() {

         $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
             var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker().val();
         alert(date);
     };
    });
```

XX will change dynamically.

But this is asynchronous and this doesn't return the value to the "openDatepicker" function. How can I call the function and return the value when clicking the date?

Comment: Can you explain to me how the XX text changes dynamically? Perhaps with that information I can update my answer to help you.

Comment: it doesnt have a rule, I have so many forms, with some different day/month/year codes, (and they can grow up in future) and I have to use javascript/jquery standard functions

Comment: I updated the code with news

Comment: @cucuru What are you trying to do? What do you mean by clicking on image? Do you mean calendar widget popup and selection of date? could you possibly post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit verbose but you could use classes in this case.  I added a wrapper to make it easier to work with:

```
<div class="pickergroup">
  <input class='dayme' name="day" id="day">
  <input class='monthme' name="month" id="month">
  <input class='yearme' name="year" id="year">
  <input class='calendario'>
  <input class="hidden datepicker">
</div>
```

Removed the click handler from markup and put it in code:

```
 $(function() {
   $(".pickergroup").find(".datepicker").datepicker({
     firstDay: 0,
     monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March',
       'April', 'May', 'June',
       'July', 'August', 'September',
       'October', 'November', 'December'
     ],
     dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
     dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
     dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   });
   $('.pickergroup').on('click', '.calendario', function() {
     var mycontainer = $(this).parent('.pickergroup');
     var dp = mycontainer.find('.datepicker');
     dp.show().datepicker('show').hide();//work around hidden element x position
     var pdate = dp.datepicker('getDate');
     if (pdate) {
       var day = pdate.getDate();
       var month = pdate.getMonth() + 1;
       var year = pdate.getFullYear();
       mycontainer.find('.dayme').val(day);
       mycontainer.find('.monthme').val(month);
       mycontainer.find('.yearme').val(year);
     }
   });
 });
```

CSS to hide the input for datepicker:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/mct4owch/

I added the onSelect so you could see it as it IS selected:

```
$(function() {
  $(".pickergroup").find(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, dpInst) {
      var mycontainer = $(this).parent('.pickergroup');
      console.log(dateText);
      var pdate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      if (pdate) {
        var day = pdate.getDate();
        var month = pdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = pdate.getFullYear();
        mycontainer.find('.dayme').val(day);
        mycontainer.find('.monthme').val(month);
        mycontainer.find('.yearme').val(year);
      }
    },
    firstDay: 0,
    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March',
      'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September',
      'October', 'November', 'December'
    ],
    dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
  $('.pickergroup').on('click', '.calendario', function() {
    var mycontainer = $(this).parent('.pickergroup');
    var dp = mycontainer.find('.datepicker');
    dp.show().datepicker('show').hide(); //work around hidden element x position
    var pdate = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    if (pdate) {
      var day = pdate.getDate();
      var month = pdate.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = pdate.getFullYear();
      mycontainer.find('.dayme').val(day);
      mycontainer.find('.monthme').val(month);
      mycontainer.find('.yearme').val(year);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it works when I have just one datepicker, but when have 2 in the same html it puts the values in the first one always! how can I do this having 2 datepicker?

Comment: @cucuru  Works for me with multiple using the modified markup.  See the fiddle for the working example with two in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery starts-with selector syntax to find the IDs.

```
$('id^=day').val($('id^=day').val()+selectedDay);
$('id^=month').val($('id^=month').val()+selectedMonth);
$('id^=year').val($('id^=year').val()+selectedYear);
```

As a reminder, the starts-with selector will find *all* HTML elements whose ID starts with that text so it's important to make sure that there is only one element with an ID that starts with 'day', 'month' and 'year' otherwise you may get unexpected results.

[Reference: jQuery starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: thanks, sometimes I have more than one datepicker in the same html code, so I cant use this. Thanks anyway!